Django Error DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'xx.xx.xx.xx' again and again
Error:
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '3.17.142.65'. You may need to add '3.17.142.65' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
I am trying to deploy my django site om AWS EC2 while deploying through github using git clone on AWS live cli. I am getting the following errors again and again. My EC2 instance ip is 3.17.142.65 and in my settings file first i kept it like this ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['3.17.142.65', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'] this shows me the same error then i changed it to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['3.17.142.65']
this also giving same error. (One thing i am not getting like i cloned my github project once at starting after then if i am changing on my github setting file how aws cli knows these changes. Btw i run the command git pull origin master Am i right that i should run this command while making any changes on github files? )
I am new to ubuntu and deploying websites so please guide me what mistake i am dong here.
To run the server i executing these commands
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo service gunicorn restart
sudo service nginx restart

My Configured Nginx file
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 3.17.142.65;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}


If you added that value to ALLOWED_HOSTS but you are still seeing error messages telling you to add the value to ALLOWED_HOSTS then it seems like you either added it to the wrong file, or you didn't restart Django after adding it.

@MarkB I added it to settings file only (but how aws know that i made changes in my github settings file is there and command to update aws? if there please let me know. ) and executed thes commands to run server 'sudo systemctl restart nginx, sudo service gunicorn restart, sudo service nginx restart' is these correct commands?

If you are only updating the settings in GitHub, and not deploying those changes to the server, then your changes aren't making it to AWS at all.

@MarkB So what's the commands to deploy on server after making changes?

There isn't a single "command" to do that. It depends entirely on your infrastructure, how you initially deployed the project to the server, and if you are using anything like AWS CodeDeploy or AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I just executed these commands to tell EC2 server, the changes which i made on github files
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master


use ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']    its automatically allowed all host ip
are you open port on ec2 ?

i did it to its also giving me same error.

are you open port on ec2 ?

how can i do this

check

enable site of nginx 2. location of source file its also matter


in security groups inbound rules i set the HTTP 80, SHH 22, ALL TCP 0-65535

If the port wasn't open, the requests would never hit Django, and those logs would not be showing up.

@MarkB But my port is open as i mentioned in my above comment.

@RahulVerma I was pointing out that the port is obviously open already, so it makes no sense that they are asking about it.

@MarkB So where i doing mistake i tried a lot but getting the same error
